# Finding the general solution of a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the general solution of the equation $$\ 2\sin^2x+5\sin { x } \cos { x } -8\cos^2x=-2$$

**My working:**
$\ 2\sin^2x+5\sin { x } \cos { x } -8\cos^2x+2=0$
$\ 2\sin^2x+5\sin { x } \cos { x } +8\sin^2x-6=0$
$\ 10\sin^2x+5\sin { x } \cos { x } -6=0$
$\ 5-5\cos2x+5\sin { x } \cos { x } -6=0$

I am giving my working for the sake of it...I know I'm getting nowhere. I really need a hint as to how I can take this forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\sin ^{ 2 }{ x } +5\sin { x } \cos { x } -8\cos ^{ 2 }{ x } =-2\\ \\ 2\sin ^{ 2 }{ x } +5\sin { x\cos { x }  } -8\cos ^{ 2 }{ x } =-2\cdot 1=-2\left( \sin ^{ 2 }{ x+\cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  }  \right) $$
$$4\sin ^{ 2 }{ x } +5\sin { x } \cos { x } -6\cos ^{ 2 }{ x } =0\quad \left( divide\quad both\quad to\quad \cos ^{ 2 }{ x } \quad  \right) $$
$$4\tan ^{ 2 }{ x+5\tan { x } -6=0 } \\ \tan { x } =\frac { -5\pm 7 }{ 8 } $$

$$\tan { x } =-\frac { 3 }{ 2 } \Rightarrow x=-\arctan { \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  } +n\pi ,n\in   \mathbb{Z}  \\ \tan { x } =\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \Rightarrow x=\arctan { \frac { 1 }{ 4 }  } +n\pi ,n\in \   \mathbb{Z}  $$

Comment: there wouldn't be any specific angle, right?

Comment: @OsheenSachdev,yes